# Store json values to an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hello I have not much experience but usually with some help of google I can figure it out, but not today. I am making an appointment program and I am struggling with blocking values from a DB in the datepicker.

JS:

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      minDate: 2,
      maxDate: "1w",
      beforeShowDay: function(date)
      {
          var dates = new Array();
          $.ajax({
              url:"load_days.php",
              type:"POST",
              success:function(data)
              {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                  dates.push(data)
                }
              },
              dataType:"json"
            })
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
            return [ dates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

PHP file:

```
$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $data[] = array(
        'day'     =>  date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row["start_event"]))
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: _struggling with blocking values from a DB in the datepicker_???

Comment: Maybe something's missing here, for one: `dates.push(data)`. That will push the entire data onto dates, won't it?

Comment: Whats is the problem? Specify it here.

Comment: I mean, the indentation is a bit off, but your ` return [ dates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]` statement runs, before your ajax call completes. so the it basically will be `return [ true ]`. But as mentioned by previous commenters, include a clear problem statement, and what you want to achieve. And as @Don'tPanic mentions, `dates.push(data)` should probably be `dates.push(data[i])`

Comment: Also, this is going to run for every date shown on the calendar. Probably don't want to make the same call to load_days.php so many times

Comment: @ABDULLOKH MUKHAMMADJONOV I want to block days that are already booked. So I want to block the days I have in my DB. And when I try dates.push(data[i]) it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest modifying the PHP script to remove the `['day' => date]` array wrapper around the date of each event. That will make it easier for JavaScript to find dates in the array.

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    $data[] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row["start_event"]));
}
```

Then I would reorganize the JS a bit so that the dates from load_days.php are only loaded once and then reused rather than reloaded in each beforeShowDay event. After reformatting the data that PHP is returning as shown above, the array returned by ajax can be used directly, so the for loop is no longer needed to transform it.

```
$( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "load_days.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (dates) {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                minDate: 2,
                maxDate: "1w",
                beforeShowDay: function(date)
                {
                    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
                    return [dates.indexOf(string) === -1]
                }
            })
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
})
```